# Installing tikz-network for texmaker

Tags: texlive, texmaker

I have a macbook pro, and texmaker on my macbook. I want to use tikz-network, but it is not installed. How do I install it? I've tried Tex Live Utility, but it doesn't list tikz-network under the packages, so I'm at a loss as to how to install it. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Dave

Answer (score 1):

Well, I just answered my own question. I needed to re-install texmaker and update the Tex Live Utility. Once I did that, tikz-network appeared on the utility and I installed it.